# Is it possible to get Nifi to Put to multiple HDFS folders?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi

I need to stream a bunch of json files to Nifi, which will then go to HDFS. Nifi needs to look at the creation date (UNIX format) within the json file and then route it to the appropriate HDFS folder. So far I have the processors set up like this:

Consume Kafka -> RouteOnContent (using regex ^"creationDate": \"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$) -> PutHDFS

There is an HDFS folder for every day, like "2019-01-28", "2019-01-29", "2019-01-30" etc. However, the "PutHDFS" processor will just output to a single directory and I obviously don't want to have 365 processors. And as far as I know, Nifi doesn't have a way to create HDFS folders dynamically so is there an elegant way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/index.html

there is a parameter `Directory`in `PutHDFS` processor:

The parent HDFS directory to which files should be written. The directory will be created if it doesn't exist.
Supports Expression Language: true (will be evaluated using flow file attributes and variable registry)

so you can use expression like `${creationDate}` for this parameter

Comment: Instead of RouteOnContent you can use EvaluateJsonPath to extract creationDate into a flow file attribute then make your Directory in PutHDFS like "/data/${creationDate}"

Comment: Ok thanks to both of you, I was wondering how to put this into a flow file attribute. I don't know much about Nifi expression language, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: So if I want to get a better idea of how to do this in Nifi expression language, should I ask here or start a new question?

Comment: I guess it'll be another subject. So better ask a new one.

Comment: The response from @dagget use NiFi expression language and is the simplest way to do that, maybe you didn't fully understand what he explained.